# Android: Facebook Hash keys parameters confusion

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi I am trying to add hash keys to in fb development portal. But I am confused of what needs to be changed and what needs to be left untouched.

1. For Dev environments, to generate hash keys, we need to run:

Mac:
    keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Do we only need to edit `~/.android/debug.keystore` and give out location or is there anything else we need to change like the word 'androiddebugkey' before generating the hash key.

2. For production environment:

   `key tool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Do we only need to edit YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS & YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH ? If yes what do we need to give the name for YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, open your Activity and create function:

```
 try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "your.application.package.name",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
 }
```

Open logcat when running your activity and search logcat with "KeyHash".

Comment: what are we trying to achieve with this piece of code exactly ? I am getting invalid hash key when i am trying to login with Facebook even though I generated and uploaded hash key

Comment: @TiagoOliveira, it will work with release key if you you choose **No filter** and search KeyHash.

Comment: @AzharAli, you can call this code above at any time you want, it will generate keyhash for you. you search in logcat **KeyHash**.

Comment: sorry, i was not thinking outside the box, yep it will work i was thinking with the realese build type and not the debug build type

Comment: @RoShanShan Thank you. For Release key, where should we choose and set NoFilter ?

Comment: you don't need to set Nofilter add this to your search in console: `KeyHash:` if you set NoFilter it will be super hard to find the hash because you will get logs for the whole system but make sure the filter is set to Show only selected application

Comment: @AzharAli, In logcat of Android studio, you can see dropdown: Show selected application, No Filter. When you sign your app with release key, you cannot filter package when you run your app, so you choose no filter and search KeyHash

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that `keytool` is one word. The second item is that facebook's documentation shows you exactly what to replace:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash

i.e. You replace the `ALIAS` of the release keystore and the `PATH` of the release keystore

With regards to your debug keystore, you don't need to replace anything but the `PATH` as `androiddebugkey` is a default alias for debug environments.

For the names, you will need to provide the `ALIAS` that you setup the Release keystore with in the first place, and the `PATH` of the `.keystore` file.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#_Create_a_Private_Keystore_

Answer (score 1):

The alias is the name that identifies your key, when you create a new keystore you have to set the key alias this is the name you have to put in the command, you also have to set the path to the keystore (don't forget the file extension)

You can take a look to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html